# Get product FINAL price without loading entire product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, price, product-collection, special-price

I can get **product attributes** efficiently without **loading the entire product** by using:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

However, I can only do this with the `price` 'attribute, since `final_price` is technically not an attribute. Since I'm grabbing a few hundred products on one page load, and the only data I need is the product's final price, doing this is very inefficient:

```
foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    $finalPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getFinalPrice();
    ....
}
```

Since I'm loading the entire product. If anybody can suggest a more efficient way, I would really appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

*"a more efficient way"* is to use product collcections where final price is already add to. Some numbers here: [What is faster - getting raw attribute value or use collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148368/what-is-faster-getting-raw-attribute-value-or-use-collection/148479#148479)

Using `->addFinalPrice()` will add something like this to collection query ...

> , `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`

and

> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0

I'd us a colletion like

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addIdFilter($productIds)
    ->addFinalPrice();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $finalPrices[] = $product->getFinalPrice();
}
```

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    2,131,092 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 2,109,925 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  4,776,976 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  4,829,112 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    103,275

compared to

```
foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    $finalPrices[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getFinalPrice();
}
```

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    116,555,318 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 114,323,845 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  22,853,768 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  23,126,448 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    5,465,676